# VS Code editor.autoIndent

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

I can't figure out what VS Code's editor.autoIndent setting does. I've tried copy+pasting unindented code with the settings turned on and off and the code is just pasted as it was copied - unindented.

Can someone please explain to me what this setting does and a clear use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't paying attention to the `Extensions with indentation rules of the language must be available` part of the `editor.autoIndent` description. I installed the [Prettier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), added it's identifier to `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` and `editor.autoIndent` now works perfectly.

I've also created a [video explaining it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1W7ExCYBz4&list=PLVwLx67OHLu1HIbCihg3cohaM5eCarbiQ&index=58), which might help.

Answer (score 0):

Many modules in vscode may provide some code formatting, depending on the language to format ...

And there is EditorConfig (https://EditorConfig.org) that should simplify this task, quickly, and once for all environments, as long it is largely supported by other IDE.

Any way, in order to format your code, you'll have to ask for this action, usinf either the `F1` key + "format this document", or `Ctrl+Maj+I`

Comment: I installed the Prettier extension and autoIndent works now. I had to add the Prettier identifier "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" to my settings to autoIndent could work. It's also automatic, you don't need to manually format it. Thanks!